# Can I use the Google App Engine without activating my free trial?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just want to use the free tier (doesn't matter if I would have to put in my credit card) without 'wasting' my free trial -- I think so much money for trial could be spent better elsewhere...

If I visit the [GCP Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) now, I see a box saying "Sign up for a free trial and you'll get $300 in credit and 60 days to explore Google Cloud Platform." and buttons Dismiss and Sign up for free trial. However, there are still cards (in the main Dashboard space) cards saying Try Compute Engine (button Get Started), *Try App Engine* (button Get Started), create a GCS bucket...

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free trial is available to test paid Google Cloud Platform services.

If you don't need to use any paid services at the moment, you can just ignore them. You can just go ahead and deploy your app engine app. This will remove all the getting started links from your app's home dashboard :)

Comment: Thanks for such a lightning fast response! Will I need to put in my credit card?

Comment: You wouldn't need to add credit card info if you're not using any paid cloud services, but now and again you might need to test out the free tier of some billable gcp services and you'll need to have payment info on deck just in case you go overboard :D

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll I know it's a a bit old Qs: I want to test GAE for a toy application and not interested to put my CC. What is limit in terms of both Data stored and Requests/Bandwidth? Thanks

Comment: @Volatil3 you'll find information about app engine's free tier limits here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Answer (score 1):

Trying GAE is independent of the GCP free trial. Or at least it was ~1.2yr ago when I started playing with GAE. At the time GAE wasn't included in GCP, it had its own console/etc. I ran into the free GCP trial later on and started/wasted it accidentally when checking out a Cloud Storage related tutorial (yep, a `Create your GCS bucket button`!)

You *might* be OK as long as you don't use Cloud services (like Cloud Storage or Compute Engine). If you do want to use those I'm unsure if you can actually "delay" starting the free trial for later :)

If you're willing to enable billing you should have no problem - you can always set your daily spending limit to 0 so that you don't actually pay (but that won't help with the 60 days trial lifetime).

Comment: Now it asks if I want to start GCP trial after clicking the *Create your GCS bucket button*. Thanks.

Comment: @hoschiCZ can I start trial later?